# Graphs with non-disjoint odd cycles satisfies $\chi \le 5$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a graph $G$ with the property that any two odd cycles in the graph share a  vertex, then show that the chromatic index of the graph, $\chi$, is at most $5$.

Comment: Two things you can do to improve your question. First, fully state the question itself in the main text, not just in the title. Second, state what you know about the problem, what you have tried, where specifically you have trouble. If you do not tell people those things then they are less motivated to write an answer, because they may be wasting their time with an answer you do not care about.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 10):

Let $C$ be the smallest odd cycle in $G$.  Note that $C$ has no chords (i.e. edges between its vertices that aren't part of the cycle), as otherwise there would be a smaller odd cycle.  Hence we can color $C$ with $3$ colors, and it will be a valid partial coloring of G.

Now if we throw all the vertices in $C$ from $G$, the remaining graph is bipartite because any odd cycle in $G$ must share a vertex with $C$ by assumption. Now we can color all of those vertices with two new colors. We have colored $G$ with $5$ colors, so $\chi(G) \le 5$.

Answer (score 5):

We can do better. In fact, we will have $\chi(G) \le 3$ for such a graph.

First, a lemma.

**Lemma:** Let $G$ be a graph with no odd cycles. Then $G$ is $2$-colorable.

**Proof:** Pick an arbitrary vertex $v\in G$. Color all vertices an even distance away from $v$ one color, and an odd distance away from $v$ another color. Note that this coloring is well defined precisely because there are no odd cycles. $\square$

Now, suppose $G$ is a graph such that all odd cycles intersect in one and only one vertex. Call it $w$. Then the graph $G'$ obtained from $G$ by removing $w$ is a graph with no odd cycles. Hence $G'$ is $2$-colorable. Add $w$ back and color it a third color. This is  $3$-coloring for $G$. Hence $\chi(G) \le 3$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. That was a nice proof. But it seems some things convey  wrong meaning..... By
"every odd cycle in this graph be common in only and only one vertex." I mean that every two odd cycle are common on one vertex not more. not ALL cycle are  common at only one point !
sorry for this Confusion; I edited title to be more clear.

Comment: Again, editing the title is not sufficient. Put the fully stated question into the text. Otherwise those who want to help you may be misled, as happened here.

Comment: @LeeMosher I hope it be clear now; Thanks a lot again.